# What are bindings in Perl?

Tags: perl, binding, terminology

I've been trying to learn Perl, and on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/), I came across

> [Perl bindings for the libsvm Support Vector Machine library](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Algorithm%3a%3aSVM)

What does *bindings* mean in this context?

I've never found this word before in computer science...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding

Comment: Thanx, cjm. Your previous answer was interestin', why have you removed it?

Comment: That was Radu's answer, not mine.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of binding is the one that lets you use a library/API from one language (usually C, including in this case) in another language (in this case Perl).

Answer (score 0):

An interface, a module that gives you access to the C library.

For example, my favorite XML parser is XML::LibXML, except it doesn't do any parsing. It's actually a glue layer that binds the objects and methods of the C++ libxml2 library to Perl objects and methods.